# lwc - wire adaptor not taking in variables as arguments only hardcoded values

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to pull in picklist values of a field based on record type. The below works -

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: 'Case', recordTypeId: '0123h000000kv04AAA' })
typePicklistValues({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log(data.picklistFieldValues.Type.values)
        this.options = data.picklistFieldValues.Type.values;
    }
}
```

If I replace the ObjectAPIName & recordtype with a variable, it doesn't work -

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: '$this.objectName', recordTypeId: '$this.recordTypeId' })
typePicklistValues({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log(data.picklistFieldValues.Type.values)
        this.options = data.picklistFieldValues.Type.values;
    }
}
```

All those variables have the actual values, which I checked already, is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reactive properties are not `$this.whatever`, but rather just `$whatever`:

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: '$objectName', recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId' })
```

Reactive variables can only work on class properties, so the wire service presumes that you meant `this`.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, careless mistake, but still I wouldn't have figured that out.